# Changing the colour of list texts in a post

Tags: css, wordpress

please how do I change the colour of list texts to match with that of a post on a wordpress site. I am using a dark theme background and while I have been able to change the colour of the posts itself to white, it doesn't seem to have any effect on the lists that were made on the post as those are still black, what code can I use to change that.

Comment: Please provide some more useful information like a link to your project or theme you are using. Show us exactly what do you want to change, otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: It's a problem related to your css. Some elements definition need to be modify. In your them css file style.css, you need to find ul or li definitions and replace or modify with `ul li { color: #FFFFFF; }`.

Comment: Read how to ask an answerable question here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask